# Attempted import error: 'app' is not exported from 'firebase/app' (imported as 'firebase')

Tags: javascript, firebase, npm, firebaseui

Encountered a very weird issue. When trying to import firebase, I got the following error:

```
./node_modules/firebaseui/dist/esm.js
Attempted import error: 'app' is not exported from 'firebase/app' (imported as 'firebase').
```

The structure of my project is: A parent folder containing a react client folder. I installed firebase in the parent folder, initialize a firebase app in the firebaseConfig file in the parent folder, and then import it into the react client folder.

I later tried installing firebase in the react client folder and import firebase in it. Weirdly, after I installed firebase in the client folder, doing "npm ls firebase" in the client folder returns empty, even though firebase is indeed in the node modules and package.json in the client folder. I am wondering what caused the problem.

**firebaseConfig.js in the parent folder**

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/firestore';
import 'firebase/auth';

const firebaseConfig = {
    ......
};

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export default firebase;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately, you've upgraded your "firebase" dependency to 8.0.0 but the "firebaseui" dependency doesn't support it yet.  You will have to temporarily downgrade firebase to version 7.24.0 until firebaseui supports the [breaking changes in 8.0.0](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js#version_800_-_october_26_2020).

Comment: firebase must support the updated version as it can cause confusions among begginers.But still my error remains there

Comment: firebaseui will eventually be updated to support 8.0.0. It is always behind, as it's maintained by different people.

Comment: Sir I am getting an error that ./node_modules/firebaseui/dist/esm.js
Attempted import error: 'app' is not exported from 'firebase/app' (imported as 'firebase').

Comment: @I am unable to resolve it have tried many things.If I open a question can you please answer that one as I have to complete olx clone

Comment: Sir should I run the npm i command in my project after changing downgrading the version of firebase but that doesn't resolve the issue in my case

Comment: Thanks for the info Doug!

Answer (score 2):

Its an update issue, while you can fix how you import firebase, you can't fix how it's imported imported in libraries you use, you'll have wait for those library to be update.

Before 8.0.0

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app'
```

After 8.0.0

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app'
```

Library's like FirebaseUI authentication

Comment: thanks for this. i'm a noob and this answer solves my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase version I was using Firebase>8.0.0 
Line of code I was using `import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';` this import works for Firebase<8.0.0 
 
 Please go and use this `import firebase from 'firebase/app';` 
 if you are using firebase>8.0.0 as of now (4th Aug 2021) things might change on later versions. 
This is because you are using the wrong line of code, nothing wrong with the system.
 Go and check the package.json file on your project folder.

Check here package.json

[Checking firebase version on package.json file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wDB2I.png)

Answer (score 0):

When I installed firebase, by default it has installed the version of 9.0.0. And I see the mentioned error but when I changed it to 8.9.1 and imported it as below it worked for me.

> import firebase from 'firebase/app'

Answer (score -1):

First determine your firebase version:

```sh
firebase --version
```

If you are using version 9, replace this line

```js
import firebase from "firebase/app"
```

with

```js
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app'
```

Reference:
https://exerror.com/attempted-import-error-firebase-app-does-not-contain-a-default-export-imported-as-firebase/