# React JS, Firebase, TypeError: Cannot read property 'initializeApp' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, npm

Everything works fine until I install "npm install react-transition-group --save".
Then somehow I got this "TypeError: Cannot read property 'initializeApp' of undefined" error.

[Very similar to this post, but I still can't get it to work.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64545862/upgrade-to-firebase-js-8-0-0-attempted-import-error-app-is-not-exported-from)

I also tried reinstall all the package, didn't work as well.

[image: The error I got.]

Here is my firebase config file.

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/auth';
import 'firebase/storage';

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "XXX",
  authDomain: "XXX",
  projectId: "XXX",
  storageBucket: "XXX",
  messagingSenderId: "XXX",
  appId: "XXX"
}

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export const auth = firebase.auth();
export default firebase;
```

Does anyone know what went wrong? Thanks a lot for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have already solved the issues, it is due to after ruining "npm audit-force", it changed some of the packages' version in the package.json.
After I compared the version numbers from the github repository, and changed them to the correct version, then run npm install. It solved the problem.