# How do I fix a Firebase 9.0 import error? "Attempted import error: 'firebase/app' does not contain a default export (imported as 'firebase')."

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am trying to implement firebase in my React application but it seems my version of importing is outdated.
Here is my code:

```
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/auth";

const app = firebase.initializeApp({
  apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
  appId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_APP_ID,
});

export const auth = app.auth();
export default app;
```

I've replaced my config keys with process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE... as they are stored in another local .env file. I've also tried different ways of importing firebase, but it seems most posts are outdated. This is the error I am getting:

> ./src/firebase.js
> Attempted import error: 'firebase/app' does not contain a default export (imported as 'firebase').

I also have another file for authContext so I will need to keep the 'auth' keyword in my firebase.js file:

```
import React, { useContext, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { auth } from "../firebase";

const AuthContext = React.createContext();

export function useAuth() {
  return useContext(AuthContext);
}

const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState();

  function signup(email, password) {
    return auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      setCurrentUser(user);
    });

    return unsubscribe;
  }, []);

  const value = {
    currentUser,
    signup,
  };
  return <AuthContext.Provider value={value}>{children}</AuthContext.Provider>;
};

export default AuthProvider;
```

Comment: v9 drastically changed, have you checked the docs?

Answer (score 104, accepted):

With version 9 things changed a bit for importing firebase, but there is no need to downgrade to a previous version, there is a "compatibility" option so can use the /compat folder in your imports, like this

```
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
```

From the Firebase [upgrade guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade#update_imports_to_v9_compat):

> In order to keep your code functioning after updating your dependency
> from v8 to v9 beta, change your import statements to use the "compat"
> version of each import. For example:
>
> ```
> // v9 compat packages are API compatible with v8 code
> import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
> import 'firebase/compat/auth';
> import 'firebase/compat/firestore';
> ```

Comment: Dude, i literally cannot do this. I am running into all sorts of issues. Only v8 works I cannot simply change the imports. There has to be something else.

Answer (score 14):

The error comes when you are using Firebase greater than V8.

There is an easy fix for this though, firebase includes backward compatibility. All you need to do is change your import from **firebase/app** to f**irebase/compat/app**.

This will change:

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/firestore';
import 'firebase/auth';
```

to:

```
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import 'firebase/compat/firestore';
import 'firebase/compat/auth';
```

Answer (score 11):

Follow the instructions in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup), which specifically calls out the steps for version 9:

> 1. Install Firebase using npm:
>
> ```
> npm install firebase
> ```
>
> 2. Initialize Firebase in your app and create a Firebase App object:
>
> ```
> import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
>
> // TODO: Replace the following with your app's Firebase project
> configuration const firebaseConfig = {   //... };
>
> const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
> ```

This is completely different than any method for any previous version of the Firebase SDKs.  Note that you are importing individual functions from the Firebase SDK, not objects or namespaces.

To work with Firebase Auth, again follow the instructions in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/start) for v9:

```
import { getAuth, createUserWithEmailAndPassword } from "firebase/auth";

const auth = getAuth();

createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
```

Again note that you're importing functions to call directly, not objects with methods.

Compare to the old process with version 8: [Upgrade to Firebase JS 8.0.0: Attempted import error: 'app' is not exported from 'firebase/app' (imported as 'firebase')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64545862/upgrade-to-firebase-js-8-0-0-attempted-import-error-app-is-not-exported-from)

Comment: if its modular like that, it makes no sense  anymore to use some ContextProvider to wrap your react apps, I can instead just simply import the functions directly in my files, right?

Answer (score 3):

1. Check your firebase version using the following command on npm

   $ firebase -V
2. If your firebase version is v8 import as following

   import firebase from "firebase/app"
   import "firebase/auth"
3. If your firebase version is v9 import as following

   import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
   import 'firebase/compat/auth';

Answer (score 2):

You should downgrade your firebase version to 8.9.1 if you are using version 9.0

and then import firebase like this:

import firebase from "firebase/app"

Comment: I still get the same error after doing this, any other suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Firebase v9 comes with new API designed to facilitate tree-shaking (removal of unused code). This will make your app as small and fast as possible.

The `/compat` packages are created for compatibility and to make the upgrade to the modular API easier. With the downside of not getting the performance perks. To get the performance benefits of the modular design, use `getApps` instead:

```
import { getApps, initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';

if (!getApps().length) {
  initializeApp({
    // your config
  });
}
```

From the library's JSDoc: `getApps` return `A (read-only) array of all initialized apps.`.

There is also a `getApp` function that `When called with no arguments, the default app is returned. When an app name is provided, the app corresponding to that name is returned. An exception is thrown if the app being retrieved has not yet been initialized.`

Answer (score 0):

you need to do this if you are doing this on October 21 and greater days

```
import {initializeApp}  from 'firebase/app'
import 'firebase/firestore'
import 'firebase/auth'
import 'firebase/storage'
 var config = {
    apiKey: "xxxxx",
    authDomain: "xx.firebaseapp.com",
    projectId: "cxxx7",
    storageBucket: "cxxx",
    messagingSenderId: "xx",
    appId: "zzze",
    measurementId: "xxx"
}
    const firebaseApp =  initializeApp(config);

    export default firebaseApp;
```

Answer (score -1):

Uninstall and reinstall firebase to a downgraded version. I just did this, installed version 8.10.0, and works fine.