# react-redux-firebase and redux-firestore integration

Tags: firebase, react-redux, react-redux-firebase, redux-firestore

each time it comes up with a new different error:
example :  "TypeError: Object(...)" or " Cannot call reactReduxFirebase() - TypeError: Object is not a function"
I am new to firebase. and I am trying to integrate firebase with react, redux, redux-thunk.
firebase recently came up with new version v9 and there is some change in the configuration in which I got lost.
the purpose is only cloud i already a have a collection in my db called 'projects' and some dummy data in it.

config.js

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/firestore';
import 'firebase/auth';

const fbConfig = {
// my app details ///
};
firebase.initializeApp(fbConfig);
firebase.firestore().settings({ timestampsInSnapshots: true });
export default firebase;
```

Index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import './index.css'
import {createStore, compose, applyMiddleware} from 'redux';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import rootReducer from './store/reducers/rootReducer';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { reduxFirestore, getFirestore } from 'redux-firestore';
import { reactReduxFirebase, getFirebase } from 'react-redux-firebase';
import fbConfig from './config/fbConfig'

const store = createStore(rootReducer,
  compose(
    applyMiddleware(thunk.withExtraArgument({getFirebase, getFirestore})),
    reactReduxFirebase(fbConfig), // redux binding for firebase
    reduxFirestore(fbConfig) // redux bindings for firestore
  )
);

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

projectAction.js

```
export const createProject = (project)=>{
    return (dispatch, getState,{getFirebase, getFirestore})=>{
        const firestore = getFirestore();
        firestore.collection('projects').add({
            ...project, 
            authorFirstName:'mrxman',
            authorLastName:'simon',
            authorId:123456,
            createdAt:new Date()
        }).then(() => {
            dispatch({
                type: 'CREATE_PROJECT',
                project
            })
        }).catch((err) =>  {
                dispatch({  type: 'CREATE_PROJECT_ERROR', err })
            })
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow! Thanks for the detailed write up , are you seeing any errors ?

Comment: Yes, Now i have this error: Attempted import error: 'firebase/app' does not contain a default export (imported as 'firebase')

Answer (score 1):

### *Previous Answer*

It looks like you need to add “/compat” with v9

import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';

Original detailed answer  :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/68967024/13749957

*Updated Answer*

Thanks to the Codesandbox, I can see you had these issues

1. *fbconfig.js* - Added compat, Your firestore was being overwritten, fixed with `merge:true`

2.*index.js*

- React-Redux-Firebase changed to a provider pattern, you updated package.json with v3.1x. but your code was in the 2.x style, see migration guide here > https://react-redux-firebase.com/docs/v3-migration-guide.html
- https://github.com/prescottprue/redux-firestore changed with an addition to a config object
- Modified imports

3. Package.json - At this point, just run a diff :)

*CodeSandbox*

https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-lehmann-r610w?file=/src/config/fbConfig.js

[image]

Comment: it comes with another giant error: TypeError: firebase_compat_app__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.default.firestore is not a function

Comment: Did you modify all imports ?  import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import 'firebase/compat/firestore';

Comment: yes, I did. I checked all of them. every time I try something it comes up with another error

Comment: the error i have now is in index.js : TypeError: Object(...) is not a function

Comment: Can i suggest you add a stackblitz or codesandbox example removing any sensitive information?

Comment: sure, (https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-snyder-t2xnu?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: See above, I have tried to remember files changed but you may have to do a diff. - Hope this helps