# using firebase in react-native apps

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native

I am trying to configure firebase for my react native app. I get the following error:

> Attempted import error: '@firebase/app' does not contain a default export (imported as 'firebase').

I am using firebase SDK 8.2.3 and the following code to configure firebase in my app:

```
import firebase from 'firebase';
import '@firebase/auth';
import '@firebase/firestore';

const firebaseConfig = {
    ...
  };


if (!firebase.apps.length) {
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
}

export { firebase };
```

Comment: That error message looks the same as you get when trying to use the old syntax on the new (v9/modular) SDKs (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68946446/how-do-i-fix-a-firebase-9-0-import-error-attempted-import-error-firebase-app)). Are you certain you're using version 8 of the SDK? Can you show how you added your dependencies?

Comment: In my dependencies I have: "@firebase/app": "^0.7.0",
    "@firebase/auth": "^0.17.2",
    "@firebase/util": "^1.3.0", "firebase": "8.2.3",

Comment: Does `import 'firebase/auth';` without `@` work ?

Comment: I still get this error for firebase/app: Attempted import error: '@firebase/app' does not contain a default export (imported as 'firebase').

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bro just use this package

[https://rnfirebase.io/]

it is efficient and easy to use with all the use-case examples

Answer (score 0):

You have to import firebase as below

```
import firebase from "firebase/app"
```

Comment: I get this error: Attempted import error: '@firebase/app' does not contain a default export (imported as 'e').