# TypeError: firebase.firestore is not a function in react js and firebase app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, typeerror

Whenever I try to run the app, I get an error message "TypeError: firebase.firestore is not a function" Looked around online and it said to include 'firebase/firestore' as well as 'firebase' which I have done but I'm getting the same error. Been looking for a solution all day, any help is greatly appreciated!

```js
    //App.js
    import './App.css';
    import React from 'react';

    const firebase = require('firebase');
    require('firebase/firestore')
    class App extends React.Component{

      constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
          selectedNoteIndex: null,
          selectedNote: null,
          notes: null
        }
      }
      render(){
        return(
          <div>Hello World!</div>

        );

    
      }

      componentDidMount = () => {
        firebase
        .firestore()
        .collection('notes')
        .onSnapshot(serverUpdate =>{
          const notes = serverUpdate.docs.map(_doc => {
            const data = _doc.data();
            data['id'] = _doc.id;
            return data;
          });
          console.log(notes);
          this.setState({notes: notes});
        });
      }
    }

    export default App;
```

```html
    <!--Index.html-->

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
        <meta
          name="description"
          content="Web site created using create-react-app"
        />
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />
        <!--
          manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is installed on a
          user's mobile device or desktop. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/
        -->
        <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
        <!--
          Notice the use of %PUBLIC_URL% in the tags above.
          It will be replaced with the URL of the `public` folder during the build.
          Only files inside the `public` folder can be referenced from the HTML.

          Unlike "/favicon.ico" or "favicon.ico", "%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" will
          work correctly both with client-side routing and a non-root public URL.
          Learn how to configure a non-root public URL by running `npm run build`.
         -->
        <title>React App</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
        <div id="evernote-container"></div>
        <!--
           This HTML file is a template.
          If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

          You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
          The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

          To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
          To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
        -->
        <!-- The core Firebase JS SDK is always required and must be listed first -->
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.1/firebase-app.js"></script>

    <!-- TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
         https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries -->
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.1/firebase-analytics.js"></script>


    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.1/firebase-firestore.js"></script>

    <script>
      var firebase = require('firebase');
      require('firebase/firestore')
      // Your web app's Firebase configuration
      // For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
      var firebaseConfig = {
        apiKey: "a",
        authDomain: "a",
        projectId: "a",
        storageBucket: "a",
        messagingSenderId: "a",
        appId: "1:874127001000:a",
        measurementId: "a"
      };
      // Initialize Firebase
      firebase.default.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
      firebase.analytics();
      firebase.firestore();
     
      var db = firebase.firestore();

    </script>

      </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple ways to fix this, the easiest for you would be to replace

```
const firebase = require('firebase');
require('firebase/firestore')
```

with

```
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/analytics";
import "firebase/auth";
import "firebase/firestore";
```

These load firebase and its sub pieces into the react app. I believe that the issue you are having is the lack of integration between reactJS being run through tools like NPM versus firebase preferring to be run from firebase serve/deploy.

This will fix the issue, but it may cause another issue, it may cause more than 1 firebase instance to be running. A method around that would be to load firebase in a separate file see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48495381/12005274). This would also involve removing the loading of firebase from the index.html files, as they become unnecessary with this method.

If you want to use firebase serve and deploy, [this](https://romerorickyio.medium.com/react-app-hosted-on-firebase-65dab862cc59) may be of interest to you.